# Android: Pass data from the inner class in MainActivity to the Service class

Tags: android, android-service

I am trying to post data to the localhost server (WAMP) with the aid of the HttpURLConnection api. I implemented it with the help of IntentService. At the moment I am facing the problem that `jSONString` is getting nothing in the `onHandleIntent`.
I appreciate any help.

This part is being called from onLocationChanged method in the inner class "MyLocationListener" in the MainActivity:

```
String jSONString = convertToJSON(pLong, pLat, formatted);      
                Intent intent3 = new Intent(MainActivity.this, PostData.class);
                intent3.putExtra("json_data", jSONString);
                PendingIntent pintent3 = PendingIntent.getService(getApplicationContext(), 0, intent3, 0);
                AlarmManager alarm3 = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
                Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
                // for 30 mint 60*60*1000
                alarm3.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(),
                        1000, pintent3);
                startService(intent3);
```

PostData class:

```
package com.bustracker;

import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;
import android.app.IntentService;
import android.content.Intent;


public class PostData extends IntentService {


    public PostData() {
        super("some");

    }


    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String jSONString = intent.getStringExtra("json_data");
        try {
            // This is the ip address of my laptop wifi because I am running the
            // app in my device and I want to send the data to the localhost
            // server(WAMP).
            URL myUrl = new URL("http://192.168.x.x/webservice");
            HttpURLConnection myConnection = (HttpURLConnection) myUrl
                    .openConnection();
            myConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            myConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            myConnection.setUseCaches(false);
            myConnection.setConnectTimeout(10000);
            myConnection.setReadTimeout(10000);
            myConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
            myConnection.connect();
            // create data output stream
            DataOutputStream wr = new DataOutputStream(
                    myConnection.getOutputStream());
            // write to the output stream from the string
            wr.writeBytes(jSONString);
            wr.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: What happens if you attempt to read the data in onStartCommand()? (basically, just move your code in onHandleIntent() into onStartCommand()

Comment: I moved it but I am still getting null!

Comment: Ok, it was a long shot. It SHOULD work in onHandleIntent. I'll have another think.

Comment: Ok I have moved it back :) but dont you have  an idea why I am getting null for jSONString in the onHandleIntent? nothing is being passed!

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that convertToJSON() doesn't return null?

Comment: Yes I am getting the data in it I can see it.

Comment: here is the passed JSON string from now: {"latitude":50.86898824,"longitude":15.66546405,"formatted":"23.04.2015 16:36:11","route":4}

Comment: In this statement: `PendingIntent pintent3 = PendingIntent.getService(getApplicationContext(), 0, intent3, 0);`  use `PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT` instead of `0` for the last parameter, and see if that helps.